# Empty set is bounded from above

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

- $\emptyset$ is bounded from above.

Proof. Take $b$ to be any number. Then a$\leq b$ for any $a\not\in\emptyset$ because, otherwise, these would be an $a\in\emptyset$ ''such that $a>b$'' which is obvious false.

**My question is**: I didn't understand this sentence ''such that $a>b$''. Why $a<b$? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to $\emptyset$ as a subset of the real numbers.

Your argument has a typo/mistake in it. Let me try to explain my solution.

In order to show that $\emptyset$ is bounded from above, we want to show existence of some upper bound $b\in \mathbb R$ such that $a\leq b$ for all $a\in \emptyset$.

We chose any $b\in \mathbb R$ to be the upper bound.

Assume by contradiction that $\emptyset$ is not bounded from above by $b$. By definition, there is $a\in \emptyset$ such that $a\leq b$ **does not** hold, that is $a\in \emptyset$ such that $a>b$. This obviously can't be true as the set is empty.

Comment: Could we say that Assume by contradiction that $\emptyset$ is not bounded from above by $b$. By definition, there is $a\in\emptyset$ such that $a<b$ does not hold because empty set hasn't any elemet, contraduction? Is it enough for proof?